# How to get list of dependencies of Maven project in java class

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

As we are migrating our legacy project to Maven, we are facing following issue.

We have one core project say, xyz and subprojects p1, p2. To add subproject into core project we just put subproject's jar into core project. Now when this core project gets started, it try to find if there are any subprojects by checking MANIFEST file of all jars in directory WEB-INF/lib of core project.

Now in Maven project structure, there is no lib directory, so can how I can get list of all jars getting used by core project(with their path)?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven dependencies plugin shows all dependencies of your project, even transitive ones. Please try:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
```

If you need to figure out dependencies at runtime, it should be possible to inspect the classpath (which Maven sets up for you, when your project is started by Maven exec). For Java SE application without custom classloader the following should work:

```
    ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

    URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) cl).getURLs();
    for (URL url : urls) {
        System.out.println(url.getFile());
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Gunther, your solution worked for me when I made little change to your code. Instead of ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), I used "ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();" 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `pom.xml` of each project.

That's the beauty of Maven (one of them), every dependency is listed there, so you don't need to go hunting in the different directory projects.

Now, if you need to find the actual files downloaded, you should check in your `maven home` folder (MAVEN_HOME or M2_HOME).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jHades](http://jhades.github.io) to find overlapping jars:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jhades</groupId>
    <artifactId>jhades</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>

new JHades()
.printClassLoaders()
.printClasspath()
.overlappingJarsReport()
.multipleClassVersionsReport()
.findClassByName("org.apache.bval.jsr303.ApacheValidationProvider")
.findClassByName("javax.validation.spi.ValidationProvider");
```

Comment: jhades.org points to something else now. Not relevant to the answer.

Comment: Changed the link.